# Why doesn't Tcl use a dollar sign before variable names when calling "set"?

Tags: syntax, tcl

I am just going to use Perl as a comparison here:

```
$foo = 5;
print $foo;
```

sets the variable `$foo` to 5, and then prints the contents of the variable (notice that `$foo` is always accessed as `$foo`).

In Tcl:

```
set foo 5
puts $foo
```

does the same thing as the Perl counterpart.

Why doesn't Tcl set variables with the "$", but need a "$" to access a variable?
Why is this true for procedures too (e.g.`proc bar {spam eggs} {...}`)?
To me, the Tcl code *looks* like this (in pseudocode):

```
"foo" = 5 # Setting a string?
puts $foo # "$foo" is not defined.
```

(my comments only reflect what appears to be happening, not what is happening).

Another point I want to add is the clarity of this:

```
set foo foo
```

Yeah, I could always do `set foo "foo"`, but isn't `set $foo foo` more consistent?

From what I know, "foo" can be a variable or a string, depending on the situation, as seen in my last example (`set foo foo` = `set var string`), but I don't get this syntax (maybe because I'm used to Python...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the original Tcl only had the `set` command, so the only way to fetch the contents of a variable "foo" was calling `set foo`.  But as Tcl progressed into the domain of general-purpose scripting languages (recall that Tcl was envisioned as being an embeddable language where you use a thin layer of Tcl over compilcated components written in C, so one wasn't expected to use lots of variables), it was deemed that that $varname syntactic sugar is useful and so it was added.

In other words, Tcl does not use "$" in the same way as Perl does, in which the "$" means "interpret whatever follows as a scalar", neither does "$" in Tcl denote a variable.  Instead it merely a syntactic sugar for "give me the value of a variable whose name is given by the immediately following word".

Comment: This is the correct answer.  `$` was introduced simply as a shorthand for this particular usage of `[set]`.

Comment: I _think_ the basic `$` syntax was added in Tcl 2; the `changes` file doesn't go that far back (though I can say that arrays were 6.0 additions, and `set` was called `var` pre-3.0) so I'm operating on memory.

Answer (score 13):

Well, I decided to comment upon the last bits of the original question, but the comment overgrown the limit, and so I'll post it as an answer even while it does not address the indicated question.  I'll hope it will clarify some things which appear to be implied in the question though.

A note about the consistency of `set foo foo`: you're approaching Tcl in a somewhat wrong way.  Tcl is radically different from Perl or Python in that it has almost no syntax (really, like LISPs).  "set foo foo" is not a syntax for setting a variable as it could be in another language, it's a call to a command *currently* available under the name "set" and passing it two arguments--"foo" and "foo"; it's whatever is registered under the "set" command name decides what is the name of a variable and what is the value to set it to.  Likewise, looping commands are not syntax, they are commands.  Really, it worth stopping here and think that

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
  puts $i
}
```

is not merely a whimsical language designer's idea to go with curly braces instead or "normal" parentheses like in C.  Instead, here the Tcl parser parses out five words, takes the first one to be the name of a command, looks it up, and passes it the rest of the words; it's the implementation of `for` which interprets those `{set i 0}`, `{$i < 0}` etc and executes them appropriately.  The syntax is there only to specify how there words are parsed out from the input stream of characters.  And since everything is implemented using commands, your commands are able to behave no different from builtin ones; this allows you to create custom commands as powerful as `for` or `switch` (something akin to macros in LISPs).  In another language this would be equal to the ability to extend sytnax in arbitrary ways.

When this idea "clicks" , Tcl will no longer appear to be weird.
And it's this property which makes Tcl so easily extensible (and embeddable): because the commands you provide from your C side behave absolutely the same as *all* builtin commands.

Comment: Fun fact: `set set set` is legal and meaningful; it just gives three different interpretations to the `set` literal. First is a command name, second is a variable name, third is (presumably) an ordinary string.

Answer (score 4):

Think of `$foo` as meaning the *value* of the variable `foo`, ie the text which it was last set to. Now, if `foo` currently has the value `x`, `set $foo y` means `set x y`, which is clearly not what is meant. It is actually more consistent than other languages, where `foo` sometimes means the value of the variable `foo`, and sometimes the variable `foo` itself.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer, if any, could only be given by the original language designers (John Ousterhout) I guess. So the rest is open to speculation or (educated) guesses. There is some history on TCL available [here](http://www.tcl.tk/about/history.html), but upon a quick reading there is no direct answer there.

> Why doesn't Tcl set variables with the "$", but need a "$" to access a
>   variable?

My take would be that this way it is closer aligned to (UNIX) shell languages. TCL was conceived at Berkeley, arguably a strong UNIX (or BSD for that matter) environment.

UNIX shells also don't use the $ sign (or equivalent for the respective shell) when declaring or assigning variables, but require it when referencing it:

```
# bourn shell like shells (sh, bash, ksh, ...)
foo=foo
echo "The value of the variable foo is $foo."
```

Even the unholy Windows CMD.EXE processor uses a comparable method (although I guess *that* was not what TCL designers had in mind ;-)

```
REM DOS COMMAND.COM / Windows CMD.EXE
set foo=foo
echo The value of the variable is %foo%.
```

Also, "string values" (although shells are notoriously weak typed) don't generally require quotes if there are now spaces in the string value.

> Yeah, I could always do set foo "foo", but isn't set $foo foo more
>   consistent?

Well, it wasn't for the TCL designers/creators ;-)

**EDIT** I almost forgot: You could actually do the following in TCL:

```
set foo bar
set $foo something
puts $bar
```

This will actually output "something". The second line actually sets the string "something" to the value of the variable "foo", thus setting a variable named "bar" and assigning it the value "something".

Comment: That's an interesting hack, but I can't exactly say I'd be using that. The fact that `set foo foo; set $foo bar; puts $foo` prints "bar", just confuses me even more, because it shows that variables _are_ strings. I guess I'm just used to Python's `setattr` and `gettatr`. Still, is there any logical reason as to why they designed it this way?

Comment: Well, that example of course has no real value. The feature as such, however is vital and rather useful. You might want to checkout the [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.3/TclCmd/upvar.htm) command for a better example of its use.

Comment: Variables are not strings. Variable _names_ are strings. With Tcl, you must distinguish between the name and the thing itself. (This has — in general — caused philosophers much trouble over the years; computing is just a thoroughly practical application if their insights.)

Comment: The example above is even more confusing in python. Imagine the following python `y = 'bar'; x = y; y = 'foo'; print x` and than look at `y=['bar']; x = y; y[0]('foo'); print x`. The difference comes from that fact that Python has references and mutable values, while Tcl values are immutable (like python strings).