# tcl use variable in namespace name

Tags: tcl

Tcl 8.4.

I have this `namespace` tree:

```
namespace eval menu_tree {

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Main Menu
    namespace eval main_menu {
        variable title "Main Menu"
    }

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Setup Menu
    namespace eval setup_menu {
        variable title "Show Setup Information"
    }

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Help Menu
    namespace eval help_menu {
        variable title "Show Help Information"
    }
}
```

The idea was to have a function like this:

```
proc print_title {menu} {
    puts $menu::title
}
```

This would work fine with global variables. However, from what I can find, using '$' with namespace names is required. I have tried to find the answer on the web, but nothing came up. 
Does anyone know how to do it, and if it is even possible?

Thank you,
-Ilya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the key approach here is to keep in mind that "the original Tcl" did not have that "$" syntactic sugar *at all.*  The original way to get the contents of a variable is a one-argument call to `set`:

```
set foo bar ;# sets variable "foo" to contain the value "bar"
puts [set foo] ;# prints the value contained in variabe "foo"
```

Hence you'll probably should use something like

```
proc print_title {menu} {
    puts [set ${menu}::title]
}
```

so that `${menu}::title` expands to the name of a variable then `set` retrieves the value of that variable.

Note the usage of curly braces around the word "menu"--without them, Tcl would try to dereference a variable named "menu::title" which is probably not what you intended.

Another thing to observe is that the behaviour of `print_title` highly depends on the contents of the "menu" argument: after it's expanded, the `set` command must see a string which it should be able to resolve, and this is subject to [a set of rules](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M26).  It's hard to get further advice until more details is known though.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7299320/720999) for more info about on that `$` vs `set` topic.

Comment: `${menu}` was the trick. The code that finally worked is this: `puts [set menu_tree::${menu}::title]`

Comment: If you're manipulating the same variable twice in one procedure, it's going to be easier to use `upvar` to alias it to a local variable name. `upvar menu_tree::${menu}::title fruitbat; puts $fruitbat`