# Floating point exception in TCL script

Tags: tcl

i am using ns2  simulator and tcl script.on executing the following code it has raised  floating point exception error. before i have changed the rate values in the following section of the code

```
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 2.0Mb 10ms RED
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 2.0Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 1.1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n3 $n2 1.2Mb 10ms DropTail
```

it was working correctly but after it has been changed to the following i.e after i have used variables `rate02,rate12,rate23,rate32` instead of the values floating point exception occurred. can any one help?

the whole tcl code is as follows:

```
    #Create a simulator object

    set ns [new Simulator]

    global set rate02 2.0Mb 
    global set rate12 2.0Mb
    global set rate23 1.1Mb
    global set rate32 1.2Mb

    #Define different colors for data flows (for NAM)
    $ns color 1 Blue
    $ns color 2 Red
    $ns color 3 Green

    #Open the NAM trace file
    set nf [open out.nam w]
    $ns namtrace-all $nf

    #Define a 'finish' procedure
    proc finish {} {
        global ns nf
        $ns flush-trace
        #Close the NAM trace file
        close $nf
        #Execute NAM on the trace file
        exec nam out.nam &
        exit 0
    }

    #Create four nodes
    set n0 [$ns node]
    set n1 [$ns node]
    set n2 [$ns node]
    set n3 [$ns node]

    #Create links between the nodes
    $ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 rate02 10ms RED
    $ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 rate12 10ms DropTail
    $ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 rate23 20ms DropTail
    $ns duplex-link $n3 $n2 rate32 10ms DropTail

        #Set Queue Size of link (n2-n3) to 10
        $ns queue-limit $n2 $n3 20
        $ns queue-limit $n3 $n2 22

        #Give node position (for NAM)
        $ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n2 orient right-down
        $ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n2 orient right-up
        $ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 orient right

        #Monitor the queue for link (n2-n3). (for NAM)
        $ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 queuePos 0.5


        #Setup a TCP connection
        set tcp1 [new Agent/TCP]
        $tcp1 set class_ 2
        $ns attach-agent $n0 $tcp1
        set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
        $ns attach-agent $n3 $sink
        $ns connect $tcp1 $sink
        $tcp1 set fid_ 1
        #########################################
        #Setup a TCP connection
        set tcp3 [new Agent/TCP]
        $tcp3 set class_ 2
        $ns attach-agent $n3 $tcp3
        set sink2 [new Agent/TCPSink]
        $ns attach-agent $n2 $sink2
        $ns connect $tcp3 $sink2
        $tcp3 set fid_ 3

        #Setup a FTP over TCP connection
        set ftp3 [new Application/FTP]
        $ftp3 attach-agent $tcp3
        $ftp3 set type_ FTP
        ############################################
        #Setup a FTP over TCP connection
        set ftp1 [new Application/FTP]
        $ftp1 attach-agent $tcp1
        $ftp1 set type_ FTP

        #Setup a TCP connection
        set tcp2 [new Agent/TCP]
        $tcp2 set class_ 2
        $ns attach-agent $n1 $tcp2
        set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
        $ns attach-agent $n3 $sink
        $ns connect $tcp2 $sink
        $tcp2 set fid_ 2

        #Setup a FTP over TCP connection
        set ftp2 [new Application/FTP]
        $ftp2 attach-agent $tcp2
        $ftp2 set type_ FTP

         proc openTrace { stopTime testName } {
            $self instvar ns_
            exec rm -f out.tr temp.rands
            set traceFile [open out.tr w]
            puts $traceFile "v testName $testName"
            $ns_ at $stopTime \
                "close $traceFile ; $self finish $testName"
            return $traceFile
        }
        proc traceQueues { node traceFile } {
            $self instvar ns_
            foreach nbr [$node neighbors] {
                $ns_ trace-queue $node $nbr $traceFile
                [$ns_ link $node $nbr] trace-dynamics $ns_ $traceFile
            }
        }


        #Schedule events for the CBR and FTP agents
        $ns at 0.1 "$ftp2 start"
        $ns at 1.0 "$ftp1 start"
        $ns at 1.0 "$ftp3 start"
        $ns at 4.0 "$ftp2 stop"
        $ns at 4.5 "$ftp1 stop"
        $ns at 4.5 "$ftp3 stop"

        #Detach tcp and sink agents (not really necessary)
        $ns at 4.5 "$ns detach-agent $n0 $tcp1 ; $ns detach-agent $n3 $sink"
        $ns at 4.5 "$ns detach-agent $n1 $tcp2 ; $ns detach-agent $n3 $sink"

        #Call the finish procedure after 5 seconds of simulation time
        $ns at 5.0 "finish"
        $ns run
```

Comment: Tcl usually converts real floating point exceptions into things you can trap. Where exactly in the code is the problem happening? There should be a trace in the `errorInfo` global variable to say where (but if it is terminating the program, we might have to take special steps to expose it).

Answer (score 0):

Unless that "NS2" thing redefines the Tcl's [`global`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/global.htm) command, the script should supposedly read something like this:

```
#Create a simulator object

set ns [new Simulator]

set rate02 2.0Mb 
set rate12 2.0Mb
set rate23 1.1Mb
set rate32 1.2Mb

# ...

#Create links between the nodes
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 $rate02 10ms RED
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 $rate12 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 $rate23 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n3 $n2 $rate32 10ms DropTail

# ...
```

In other words, there are two problems with your code:

- The Tcl's `global` command has the semantics defined as `global varname ?varname ...?`, that is, it just *declares* the *names* which are passed to it as referring to global variables.  Hence a call `global set rate02 2.0Mb` just declares the names "set", "rate02" and "2.0Mb" to denote global variables.  Most probably not what you wanted.
- the `duplex-link` subcommand probably expects *a value* as its "rate" argument, and you're passing it *the name of a variable.*  Seemingly, some NS2 code then attempts to interpret such a string as a floating-point value, which fails for obvious reasons.  Hence you have to dereference a variable to get its value when you want to pass that variable's value to a command.  This is done using the `set varname` command or the shorthand notation using the `$` syntax: `$varname` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7299320/720999) about this).

Look like you should start with [the Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) which deals with these basics.