# Any difference of double quote a variable?

Tags: tcl

For the following code:

```
set str "a bb ccc"
if {[string first bb "$str"] >= 0} {
    puts "yes"
}
```

My college said I should not double-quote $str because there is performance difference, something like TCL makes a new object internally using $str.

I cannot find a convincing document on this. Do you know if the claim is accurate?

Comment: It is clearly not needed to quote the "$str" thing. You could probably find out if you look at the bytecode with `::tcl::unsupported::diassamble` (http://wiki.tcl.tk/21445) but performance shouldn't matter in this case, unless your in a really tight loop.

Comment: Both produces the same bytecode (in 8.6), so no performance difference. Special cases like empty string concat (`"$var[unset var]"`) have been inproved in the past and have therefore differend performance in different Tcl versions. So check the result of `::tcl::unsupported::diassemble`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your colleague is correct: if Tcl sees plain `$str` where a word is expected, it parses out that "str" as the name of a variable, looks it up in the approptiate scope, then extracts [*an internal object*](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Object.htm) representing its value from that variable and then asks that object to produce the string representation of that value.  At this point that string representation will be either already available and cached (in the object) — and it will, in your case, — or it will be transparently generated by the object, and cached.

If you put dereferencing of a variable (`$str`) in a double quoted string, then Tcl goes like this: when it sees the first `"` in a place where a word is expected, it enters a mode where it would parse the following characters, performing variable- and command substitutions as it goes until it sees the next unescaped `"`, at which point the substituted text accumulated since the opening `"` is considered to be one word and it ends up being in a (newly created) internal object representing that word's value.

As you can see, in the second (your) case the original object holding the value of a variable named "str" will be asked for its value, and it then will be used to construct another value while in the first case the first value would be used right away.

Now there's a more subtle matter. For the scripts it evaluates, Tcl only guarantees that its interpreter obeys [certain evaluation rules](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), and nothing more; everything else is implementation details. These details might change from version to version; for instance, in Tcl 8.6, the engine has been reimplemented using non-recursive evaluation (NRE), and while those were rather radical changes to the Tcl internals, *your existing scripts did not notice.*

What I'm leading you to, is that discussing of *implicit* performance "hacks" such as the one we're at now only have sense when applied to a particular version of the runtime. I very much doubt Tcl currently optimizes away `"$str"` to just re-use the object from `$str` but it could eventually  start, in theory.

The real "problem" with your approach is not performance degradation but rather an apparent self-delusion you seem to apply to yourself which leads to Tcl code of dubious style.  Let me explain.  Contrary to "more conventional" languages (usually influenced by C and the like), Tcl does not have special syntax for strings.  This is because it does not have string literals: every value starting its life in a script from a literal *is initially a string.* The actual type of any value is defined at runtime by commands operating on those values.  To demonstrate, `set x 10; incr x` will put a string "10" to a variable named "x", and then the `incr` command will force the value in that variable "x" to convert the string "10" it holds to an integer (of value 10); then this integer will be incremented by 1 (producing 11) invalidating the string representation as a side effect. If you later will do `puts $x`, the string representation will be regenerated from the integer (producing "11"), cached in the value and then printed.

Hence the code style you adopted actually tries to make Tcl code look more like Python (or Perl or whatever was your previous language) for no real value, and also look alien to seasoned Tcl developers. Both double quotes and curly braces are used in Tcl *for grouping,* not for producing string values and code blocks, respectively — these are just particular use cases for different ways of grouping. Consider reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7299320/720999) for more background.

**Update:** various types of grouping are very well explained in [the tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) which is worth reading as a whole.

Comment: Curious - how do you get so much insight into TCL interval? Tell me reading the TCL implementation source code if you have to...

Comment: @my_question, it's all in the docs, and I gave links to the pieces of them explaining both how the values in Tcl are represented and how Tcl interpreter evaluates its scripts. Unfortunately, the docs are succinct and terse, so to get gentler introductions to the concepts, [the wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk) is much better (and its's really comprehensive).

Comment: @my_question, also note that I was factually wrong, and Donal (one of those folks who actually *develops* the Tcl core) showed that the Tcl interpreter is able to optimize away your particular case to just one variable dereference without constructing a new value.

Answer (score 4):

Your colleague is actually wrong, as Tcl's parser is smart enough to know that `"$str"` is identical to `$str`. Let's look at the bytecode generated (this is with Tcl 8.6.0, but the part that we're going to look at in detail is actually the same in older versions all the way back to 8.0a1):

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {
set str "a bb ccc"
if {[string first bb "$str"] >= 0} {
    puts "yes"
}
}
ByteCode 0x0x78710, refCt 1, epoch 15, interp 0x0x2dc10 (epoch 15)
  Source "\nset str \"a bb ccc\"\nif {[string first bb \"$str\"] >= 0} "
  Cmds 4, src 74, inst 37, litObjs 7, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Commands 4:
      1: pc 0-5, src 1-18        2: pc 6-35, src 20-72
      3: pc 15-20, src 25-46        4: pc 26-31, src 61-70
  Command 1: "set str \"a bb ccc\""
    (0) push1 0     # "str"
    (2) push1 1     # "a bb ccc"
    (4) storeScalarStk 
    (5) pop 
  Command 2: "if {[string first bb \"$str\"] >= 0} {\n    puts \"yes\"\n}"
    (6) startCommand +30 2  # next cmd at pc 36, 2 cmds start here
  Command 3: "string first bb \"$str\""
    (15) push1 2    # "bb"
    (17) push1 0    # "str"
    (19) loadScalarStk 
    (20) strfind 
    (21) push1 3    # "0"
    (23) ge 
    (24) jumpFalse1 +10     # pc 34
  Command 4: "puts \"yes\""
    (26) push1 4    # "puts"
    (28) push1 5    # "yes"
    (30) invokeStk1 2 
    (32) jump1 +4   # pc 36
    (34) push1 6    # ""
    (36) done
```

As you can see (look at `(17)`–`(19)`), the `"$str"` is compiled to a push of the name of the variable and a dereference (`loadScalarStk`). That's the most optimal sequence given that there's no local variable table (i.e., we're not in a procedure). The compiler doesn't do non-local optimizations.