# Tcl upvar to a variable in another proc

Tags: tcl, upvar

I have two procs: From `MAIN` I call another proc `Glob`.
`$Allforces` is a list of lists.

```
proc ::MAIN {} {  
    # something
    ::Glob $AllForces
}

proc ::Glob {Input} {
    upvar $Input AllForces
    # do something
}
```

I get "`No such variable`" as an error for my attemt to `upvar`.
So I tried:

```
upvar $InputMPCForces ::MAIN::AllForces
```

Then I get: "`upvar won't create namespace variable that refers to procedure variable`"

How can I access `AllForces` from `MAIN` in `Glob` by reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call your proc like this:

```
::Glob AllForces
```

that is, you pass the *name* of the variable, not its value.

Then, in the proc, the `upvar` command will take the variable whose name is the value of the local variable `input` and make it available locally as AllForces

Comment: This is correct. @Lumpi, you might also be interested in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7299320/720999) to get a better idea about why that `$` is not needed when passing *the name* of a variable to a procedure.

Comment: I find it helps, mnemonically, to have arguments that will be `upvar`ed be called `SomethingName`. (In this case, `InputName`.) Then I would write `upvar $InputName Input` and have my variable by reference…